# Passing enum type to Converter with integer value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I was trying to make a Generic `IValueConverter` that I could use in a `DataGrid` binding where I would send an integer value and an enum type to convert that integer to that enum type and return a string value from the resource file. But what I couldn't do is pass the enum type to the converter because I couldn't reference my enum in my xaml code. This is the reference that I tried:

I want to reference (`UserStatus`) which is inside a class named `ERPConstants` in the namespace `ERPProject._AppControl._BAL._Core._Constants`.

I tried this in my code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ERPProject._AppUI._Users.UsersControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:Constants="clr-namespace:ERPProject._AppControl._BAL._Core._Constants">

<Grid>
<DataGrid Name="dgUsers" Grid.Row="1">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Type Constants:UserStatus}}"></Label>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

but it says `UserStatus` does not exist in the namespace. I also tried to include `ERPConstants` in the `xmlns:Constants` above and didn't work. Can anyone help in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so after some try out I got an answer myself here it is for anyone that might have the same issue
I referenced my enum as this Constants:ERPConstants+UserStatus

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Type Constants:ERPConstants+UserStatus}}"></Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```